# It is possible to secure WCF Data service, where it hosted in windows azure using ACS?

Tags: azure, wcf-data-services, odata, acs

What i am trying to do is,

1) Get a token from ACS using x509 cert credentials
2) Authenticate to the WCF Data service(OData Service)  using the ACS issued token.

is it correct?

Also, i have found another example from oData team blog
[oData team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2011/01/20/oauth-2-0-and-odata-protecting-an-odata-service-using-oauth-2-0.aspx).

Thanks in advance!!.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. 
Along with the article you refer, the complete reference [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728284.aspx).

Come back when you have concrete question on a concrete solution.